# Passagem de parametro C#

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio

Tenho o seguinte código em js

```
function consultaSolicitacao() {
id = getVar("id");
serviceURL = "/Solicitacao/ConsultaSolicitacao";
$.get(serviceURL, null, function (data) {
        var aux = data.length;
        var tblText = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < aux; i++) {
            var tmpArgs = data[i].id + ",'" + data[i].assunto
                    + "','" + data[i].mensagem + "','" + data[i].endereco + "','" + data[i].anexo + "'";
            var id = data[i].id;
            tblText += '<div id="Solicitacoes"><div>';
            tblText += '<span id="idSolicitacao">' + data[i].id + '</span>';
            tblText += '</div></div></a>';
        }
    document.getElementById("solicitacaoID").innerHTML = tblText;
});
```

}

Preciso passar o valor da minha variável 'id' para a controller:

```
public ActionResult ConsultaSolicitacao(int id)
    {
        var x = Teste.ConultaSolicitacao(id);
        return new JsonResult()
        {
            Data = x, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
```

Mas não sei como enviar a variável js para a controller.
O controller já está esperando mas não sei como faço.

Comment: Tentou `var serviceURL = "/Solicitacao/ConsultaSolicitacao/" + id;`?

Comment: Deste jeito ele passa no link e não por parâmetro, dai da erro.O link fica assim http://localhost:18376/Solicitacao/ConsultaSolicitacao2

Comment: Faltou uma barra antes do `2`, leia de novo o meu exemplo.

Comment: Nossa deu certo, muito obrigado

Comment: E se eu precisar passar 2 variaveis? Tentei assim mas esta dando erro. `var serviceURL = "/Solicitacao/UpdateDepartamentos/" + id_Departamento + id_Solicitacao;` e assim tambem `var serviceURL = "/Solicitacao/UpdateDepartamentos/" + id_Departamento, id_Solicitacao;`

Answer (score 7):

Como a sua requisição usa o método GET do HTTP, o parâmetro deve fazer parte da própria URL. Então a URL terá o seguinte formato:

```
/Solicitacao/ConsultaSolicitacao/id
```

Parece simples alterar o seu código para gerar isso:

```
function consultaSolicitacao() {
    var id = getVar("id");
    var serviceURL = "/Solicitacao/ConsultaSolicitacao/" + id;
    // resto do código
}
```

Repare que eu também coloquei `var` antes dos nomes das variáveis. Se não fizer isso, você estará criando variáveis globais inadvertidamente, o que não é uma boa ideia.

Comment: E se eu precisar passar 2 variaveis? Tentei assim mas esta dando erro.
`var serviceURL = "/Solicitacao/UpdateDepartamentos/" + id_Departamento + id_Solicitacao;`   e assim tambem                      `var serviceURL = "/Solicitacao/UpdateDepartamentos/" + id_Departamento, id_Solicitacao;`

Comment: Separe cada uma com barra: `+ id_Departamento + '/' + id_Solicitacao;`. E, claro, no C# inclua mais um parâmetro no seu método

Comment: Fiz o seguinte 
    `var serviceURL = "/Solicitacao/UpdateDepartamentos/"+id_Departamento +'/'+ id_Solicitacao;` e na minha controller esta assim `public void UpdateDepartamentos(int id_Departamento, int id_Solicitacao)` mas esta dando erro Not Found `http://localhost:18376/Solicitacao/UpdateDepartamentos/2/1`

Comment: @ViniciusVAz Aí eu já não sei (na verdade tenho pouca experiência com o asp.met mvc). Sugiro postar uma pergunta separada sobre esse caso.

Answer (score 1):

O correto a ser feito é passagem por uma Array, enviando pelo get, o meu código ficou assim

```
function consultaSolicitacao() {
id = getVar("id");
var = parametros;
    parametros = { id_Departamento: id_Departamento, id_Solicitacao: id_Solicitacao }
serviceURL = "/Solicitacao/ConsultaSolicitacao";
$.get(serviceURL, parametros, function (data) {
        var aux = data.length;
        var tblText = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < aux; i++) {
            var tmpArgs = data[i].id + ",'" + data[i].assunto
                    + "','" + data[i].mensagem + "','" + data[i].endereco + "','" + data[i].anexo + "'";
            var id = data[i].id;
            tblText += '<div id="Solicitacoes"><div>';
            tblText += '<span id="idSolicitacao">' + data[i].id + '</span>';
            tblText += '</div></div></a>';
        }
    document.getElementById("solicitacaoID").innerHTML = tblText;
});
```

E a Controller fica esperando os parametros

```
    public ActionResult ConsultaSolicitacao(int id, int id_Solicitacao){}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode passar dessa forma também.

```
Id = getVar("id");

$.ajax({
        url: '/Solicitacao/ConsultaSolicitacao',
        data: { id: Id},
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (dados) {

        },
        error: function () {

        }
});
```